# Inno setup user selected component must be remember in re installation

Tags: installation, inno-setup

We have one setup file that have three options e.g option 1, option 2 and and then check box. everything is working perfect. Now we got new demand from customer that what ever selection user has selected in installation must be remembered in reinstallation.

If user selected like first option button and user un install application and user will install it again then the section option will be selected by default like first option button.

Same if user has selected like 3rd checkbox button and uninstall the applicaton and install it again then the 3rd button will be selected automatically.

Here is component section.
       [Components]

```
 Name: MediaSupport; Description: Media Support; Types: full; Flags: fixed
 Name: MediaSupport\C1; Description: Option one; Types: full; Flags: Exclusive
 Name: MediaSupport\B1; Description: Option 2; Flags: Exclusive
 Name: MediaSupport\B1\Test; Description: Option 2.1; Types: full; Flags: dontinheritcheck
```

Any hint?[image]

Regards

Comment: You can store the selection as a sensible value (e.g. as a bitmask) by the `SetPreviousData` function and read it back by the `GetPreviousData` function. [take this as a preliminary answer; this should be elaborated]

Comment: By default Inno *will* remember the previous selection of components and reselect them on subsequent installs, without you having to do anything.  If this is not working for you then you have probably disabled something required to support this.  Please post your `[Setup]` and `[Types]` section contents.